# Pyspark Dataframe pivot and groupby count

Tags: python, pyspark

I am working on a pyspark dataframe which looks like below

| id | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 3 | B |
| 3 | B |

I want to unstack the category column and count their occurrences. So, the result I want is shown below

| id | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Null | 3 |

I tried finding something on the internet that can help me but I couldn't find anything that could give me this specific result.

Comment: pls provide a reproducible example with minimum input and expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -- (Not sure its optimized)

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'A'),(1,'A'),(1,'B'),(2,'B'),(2,'A'),(3,'B'),(3,'B'),(3,'B')],['id','category'])
df = df.groupBy('id','category').count()
df.groupBy('id').pivot('category').sum('count').show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Short version, dont have to do multiple groupBy's

```
df.groupBy("id").pivot("category").count().show()
```