# Summary and crosstabulation in Pyspark (DataBricks)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have pyspark Data frame for which want to calculate summary statistics (count of all unique categories in that column)  and crossTabulation with one fixed column for all string columns.
For Example: My df is like this

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat1 | XYZ | A |
| Cat1 | XYZ | C |
| Cat1 | ABC | B |
| Cat2 | ABC | A |
| Cat2 | XYZ | B |
| Cat2 | MNO | A |

I want something like this

| VarNAME | Category | Count | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| col1 | Cat1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| col1 | Cat2 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| col2 | XYZ | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| col2 | ABC | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| col2 | MNO | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| col3 | A | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| col3 | B | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Col3 | C | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

So, Basically, I want cross-tabulation for all individual columns with col3 and the total count.
I can do it in Python using a loop but the loop is somewhat different in pyspark.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark Dataframe pivot and groupby count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557498/pyspark-dataframe-pivot-and-groupby-count)

Comment: yes, but partially. I have many columns so I was wondering whether  it is possible to do it without a loop

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents.

1. Created a sample dataframe

   ```
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [("Cat1","XYZ","A"),
        ("Cat1","XYZ","C"),
        ("Cat1","ABC","B"),
        ("Cat2","ABC","A"),
        ("Cat2","XYZ","B"),
        ("Cat2","MNO","A")
    ],schema = ['col1','col2','col3'])
   ```
2. Used Crosstab function which will calculate the count for all the col3, evaluates the total row count, then created a new constant column based on the column name and renamed it.
   Then performed union for all these dataframes

   ```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *
    import pyspark.sql.functions as fx

    df_union = \
    df.crosstab('col1','col3').withColumn('count',fx.expr(("A+B+C"))).withColumn('VarName',lit('col1')).withColumnRenamed('col1_col3','Category').union(
    df.crosstab('col2','col3').withColumn('count',fx.expr(("A+B+C"))).withColumn('VarName',lit('col2')).withColumnRenamed('col2_col3','Category')).union(
    df.crosstab('col3','col3').withColumn('count',fx.expr(("A+B+C"))).withColumn('VarName',lit('col3')).withColumnRenamed('col3_col3','Category'))
   ```
3. Printing the data frame based on the column order

   ```
   df_union.select('VarName','Category','count','A','B','C').show()
   ```

Please check the sample output for the reference:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I have more than 100 columns. it will be difficult to write this for 100 columns. I have done almost same thing but using loop to iterate over column but it very take long time . I have more than 1 million record.